# SQL Hive Hadoop - Multiple Wildcard Values with Like Statement

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, where-clause, sql-like

HIVE/Hadoop - How would I create a query with multiple wildcard values using the like statement (I tried similar to command but that did not work).

Example query

```
select *
from schema.table a
where a.apple = '1'
and a.berry LIKE ('A10%','B10%')
;
```

The above did not work. I did try replacing LIKE with IN but the query refuses to stop running, not sure why the IN command is causing for the query to keep running and not even produce a result. Is using OR my only option here? I have about 15 values I would like wildcard values on.

---

As a side note question to better help me understand the above problem,
I noticed my query running with no end time when using:

```
and a.berry IN ('A10%')
```

versus

```
and a.berry LIKE 'A10%'
```

Should I always use LIKE with the wildcard %?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` and `IN` can't do what you want: `LIKE` operates on scalar operands, while `IN` does not do pattern matching.

You need to repeat the expression:

```
and (a.berry like 'A10%' or a.berry like 'B10%')
```

Another option is to use a regex - this is shorter to type when the list of values gets longer:

```
and a.berry rlike '^(A10)|(B10)'
```

Or:

```
and a.berry rlike '^[AB]10'
```

Comment: For regex, let's say I had a value of C1%. Would I have to create another line since it is off by one character compared to the rest of the values? Thank you much!

Comment: @Logan: `and (a.berry like 'A10%' or a.berry like 'B10%' or a.berry like 'C10%'`... Or: `and a.berry rlike '^(A10)|(B10)|(C10)`'

Comment: For rlike, the error I am getting is Unexpected token 'rlike' was found. Expected tokens may include: "LIKE".

Comment: The error is resolved - it was on my side. For a separate question, would I be able to use ```rlike``` in Toad for DB2?